# Air exchanger "fresh air to house" wye - should I leave it open or closed?

Tags: ducts, air-quality, air-exchanger

*Background*

Just bought a house with a passive air exchanger: no internal fans, just motorized dampers moving air with the furnace fan. We have a thermopump, electric furnace and whole house bypass humidifier.

*Question*

My air exchanger has this wye right after the "Fresh air to house" with a damper that dumps right next to the furnace. It looks like a cleanout? It is simply a register for this room?

Should I leave this open or closed? When and why?

[image: air exchanger wye]

(This question is split out from but loosely related to [Air exchanger stale exhaust too restrictive? Some other issue?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/287605/air-exchanger-stale-exhaust-too-restrictive-some-other-issue))

Comment: An electric furnace will not need combustion air, so having it open/close will be more of your choice.  Can try each way and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @crip659 Ah! I hadn't considered that it would be fresh air for a combustion furnace, as this system was installed after the oil furnace was removed. Thanks.

Comment: I am just guessing, but it does look like a damper is installed, so closing/opening/adjusting is easy.  It should be in the close position right now, according to the damper handle position.

Comment: Indeed there is a damper, which I kept closed. I think it's a very logical guess.